# Limit of solving the 1D Heisenberg chain to find the dynamics numerically

Tags: computational-physics, magnetic-moment, spin-chains

I am trying to simulate the dynamics of a 1D Heisenberg chain using Python.

I am going step-by-step.
There is an external magnetic field along +Z direction.
At first we consider a single classical spin, oriented at some angle $\theta$ with the +Z axis. So particle's Hamiltonian is $H=-S_zB_z$.
Classical spin means, it can orient in any direction, with the restriction $S_x^2+S_y^2+S_z^2=1.$
The dynamics can be approximated by using Heisenberg's equation of motion: $\frac{dS_i}{dt}=-\text{i}[S_i,H]\hspace{5pt}(i=x,y,z).$
This gives: $\dot{S_x}=S_y,$ $\dot{S_y}=-S_x,$ and $\dot{S_z}=0$.
This can be easily solved using 4th order Runge-Kuta method in Python. And by plotting we get nice curves, also it can be verified that the angle of precession stays constant.

In the next step, I consider 4 particles in 1D, without any interaction in between them.
By writing required code we can get same sort of curves for all four particles.

But what happens if, in the 3rd step, we introduce *nearest neighbour interaction* and *periodic boundary condition* in the system?
The full Hamiltonian is this: $$H_{total}=-h\sum_i\vec{S_i}-J\sum_{<ij>}\vec{S_i}\cdot\vec{S_j}\hspace{10pt}(i=x,y,z),$$
$<ij>$= nearest neighbour pairs.
Then the equations of motion for the $x$-component of $i$th particle: $$\frac{dS_{x}^i}{dt}=-\text{i}[S_x^i,H]\hspace{5pt}(i=1,2,3,4)$$
with corresponding equations for $y-$ and $z-$ components.
Each of these equations will give half-a-dozen terms, in no way elimentary like the above two cases. And so preparing the relevant functions to be fed into the code, whether we use RK4 or any other numerical techniques, to get the dynamics in terms of simple curves (as we got for single particle and multi-particle no-interaction cases, respectively) feels cumbursome as well as too much of an effort.

My question is - is my confusion right? That is, at some point we must leave dynamical solution of each of the spin-components (or, *microscopic* description) and look of some other *macroscopic* observable(s).
Or, are there methods to proceed along the same line?